# WordPress Hook for user register

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

how can I tell WordPress, that if a user registers, it shall execute my function?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`user_register`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/) action hook which fires after a user has registered and passes `$user_id` as a variable:

```
add_action('user_register','my_function');

function my_function($user_id){
  //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: is there any hook just before inserting into database?

Comment: In case that someone want to know @AtifMohammedAmeenuddin question.
You can use register_post to hook before register user to db.